# Kotlin's data class == C#'s struct?

Tags: c#, kotlin

I used C# before and there we can define a `struct` which will be a value type. I'm learning Kotlin now and as far as I know kotlin `data-class` compares by value, can copy by value etc. Found some discussions online about this but it wasn't straightforward and I'd like someone skilled in C# and Kotlin to clear this up: can I interpret Kotlin's `data class` like a C# `struct` and call it a day? If no, what are the differences?

Comment: btw why is this "too broad"? If I were to ask "what is kotlin to c#?" yeah that's too broad. but I ask about one specific feature from the two that are quite akin.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs    https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html

Comment: @Amy now jokes aside, could you tell me e.g. that a kotlin data class is a reference or a value type for example? and other stuff I'm not aware of when I want to use a data class like a struct?

Comment: I have no idea why you think my last comment was an attempt at humor.  Is documentation funny to you?  Where else would you expect to look to learn how two things are similar/different?

Comment: kotlin is new, so the docs are a bit incomplete. I would learn from those who have experience with the features, used both of them as you might see in the answer I got, there is something mentioned in the answer that was missing from the docs. for comparison it would make sense if the two was written by the same person and just throwing the two docs (which I obviously looked for in the first place) is yes, kind of funny.

Comment: "which I obviously looked for in the first place"  Sorry, there is nothing obvious about this in your question.  It's actually quite the opposite.  I wouldn't have linked the docs to you if you had quoted the actual docs, demonstrating (and making it *obvious*) that you had referenced the docs.  If you consider it obvious that anyone would look at the docs before asking questions on SO, then I have a bridge to sell you.

Comment: that's fair, but I've been using SO for a while now, my rep is low, but not like 10 or 20. I know I'm expected to look for stuff to find out if it's written somewhere else so I did just that (after watching my tutorial for kotlin)

Comment: Your last sentence though, fair enough :(

Comment: You're interested in my bridge?!  *nervous excitement intensifies*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The main difference between Kotlin data classes and C# structs is that the Kotlin data classes are still *classes*, they are passed by reference (a referential type, speaking in terms of C#) and stored in the same heap with other objects (not taking possible JVM optimizations into account) instead of the stack, in the same form as the other objects.

The copy and equality check implementations for data classes are just generated into the methods of the class and are called as instance methods in a JVM-natural way.

Some limitations that the data classes have in common with structs are caused by a different reason: for example, data classes are final because of unclear semantics of the auto-generated functions that would come from data class inheritance.

Comment: So when I have a `data class` named DC, and I create `a:DC = ...; b:DC = a` that **doesn't** copy the content (like C# struct does), allocating additional memory for the members? and if I need a copy I have to use Kotlin auto implemented `copy`?

Comment: That's correct, it only copies the reference stored in `a` to a new variable `b`, the instance is the same. To copy the instance, use the generated `copy`.

Comment: Now that's a critical point right there. Btw I checked your profile to see your Kotlin related expertise and I got answer from the top :D You did good with kotlin. It will be interesting to see its impact (already widespread Java gets a C# overhaul - just with way less typing).

Answer (score 3):

Structs in C# can always be created without parameters even if they have a constructor, while data classes in Kotlin requires a parameterized constructor.

> To ensure consistency and meaningful behavior of the generated code, data classes have to fulfill the following requirements:
>
> - The primary constructor needs to have at least one parameter;
>
> ...

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html